# Rate of change vs. average rate of change of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the difference between the both? I am trying to find a separate definitions for both in a textbook, but it only defines average rate of change.

I know that average rate of change is: $$\frac { change\quad in\quad y }{ change\quad in\quad x } $$

But what is just rate of change then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *average rate of change* is defined over some finite interval $\Delta x$ to be

$$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} $$

The *rate of change* is the rate at which the function changes at one particular point and is found by taking the limit

$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} $$

Note that in the case of a linear function, $y=mx+c$, the rate of change and the *average* rate of change are identical (they both equal $m$).